# ¿Cómo pruebo un archivo con un único método usando PHP unit?

Tags: php, pruebas-unitarias, intellij-idea, phpunit

Estoy traduciendo un ejercicio de Codewars.com a PHP y quisiera correr las pruebas unitarias en mi PC Windows 10.

Para ello estoy tratando de correr las pruebas unitarias  mediante el siguiente comando que me genera el IntelliJ Idea:

Mi archivo a probar `round_to_next_5.php` contiene

```
<?php
function round_to_next_5($n)
{
    return $n % 5 == 0 ? $n : 5 - $n % 5 + $n;
}

?>
```

El archivo de prueba unitaria contiene:

```
<?php
//namespace com\codewars\hwtdstrngls;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class RoundToNextMultipleOf5 extends TestCase
{
    public function testWorksWithSomeExamples()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(round_to_next_5(0), 0);
        $this->assertEquals(round_to_next_5(1), 5);
        $this->assertEquals(round_to_next_5(5), 5);
        $this->assertEquals(round_to_next_5(6), 10);
        $this->assertEquals(round_to_next_5(12), 15);
        $this->assertEquals(round_to_next_5(9), 10);
        $this->assertEquals(round_to_next_5(16), 20);
        $this->assertEquals(round_to_next_5(22), 25);
    }
}

?>
```

**Ambos archivos los puse en la misma carpeta**

Intento correr la prueba unitaria mediante el comando que me genera el IntelliJ:

```
C:\Users\ruslan.lopez\IdeaProjects\practice-codes>C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.2.4\php.exe -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 -dxdebug.remote_mode=req -dxdebug.remote_port=9000 -dxdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1 C:\Users\ruslan.lopez\Downloads\phpunit-7.0.3.phar --no-configuration --filter "/(::testWorksWithSomeExamples)( .*)?$/" RoundToNextMultipleOf5 C:\Users\ruslan.lopez\IdeaProjects\practice-codes\src\test\php\com\codewars\hwtdstrngls\Test.php --teamcity
```

pero me produce el error:

> Error : Call to undefined function round_to_next_5()
>    C:\Users\ruslan.lopez\IdeaProjects\practice-codes\src\test\php\com\codewars\hwtdstrngls\Test.php:17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné guiándome con la pregunta en inglés [¿Es posible hacer pruebas unitarias a archivos php, en vez de archivos de clases usando PHPUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36016250/is-it-possible-to-unit-test-php-files-other-than-class-file-using-phpunit)

Simplemente agregué la línea

```
include_once 'round_to_next_5.php';
```

para referenciar al archivo que quería probar.

Esta línea puede incluirse como primera línea del método a probar o si se tienen mas métodos, se puede poner encima de la clase.

Comment: Si tienes más métodos dentro de la clase puedes probar solo uno mediante `phpunit --filter nombre_del_metodo /ruta/de/la/clase.php`

Comment: @OscarR como dice la pregunta, no hay clases, así que tu solución no aplica

Comment: Tanto en la pregunta, como en la pregunta de referencia, hay clases, que son las que extienden a _TestCase_ o a _PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase_. Más que una solución, es un dato adicional, que puede servir a otros con el mismo problema, pero buscando alternativas. Se trata de aportar y que le sirva a otros con cuestiones similares.

Comment: En el archivo round_to_next_5.php no hay clases de allí que te diga que tu solución no aplica.